# Get values from Load Event in Form.Show

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

I have two WinForm(Form1 and Form2). In the Form1 I get values enter by users(textBox, ComboBox). The second Form2 display values on controls(textBox, comboBox) called from the Event Load. In the Form2 also I overload Show

```
 Public Overloads Sub Show(ByVal searchValues As ArrayList)
```

searchValues parameter contains the values from the Form1, then I call Show from the Form1

```
 Form2.Show(SearchValues)
```

I want to compare the values from the Form1 with the values from the Form2 If the values are diferents then the value from the Form1 replace the value from the Form2. But I get Null or Empty values from the Form1 when execute `Public Overloads Sub Show(ByVal searchValues As ArrayList)`. I think this happens because it has not been executed event Load.

Comment: I got the solution by myself...

Comment: I create a global variable(Private tempSearchValue As New ArrayList) in the Form2 that will receive the value from parameter searchValues(tempSearchValue.Add(searchValues.Item(0).ToString)). Then, in the event Load Form2 I can access to this variable and modified the value of the control based on my condition. Ex: comboBox1.text = tempSearchValue. It works.

Comment: The variable scope is called a module/class level variable.  Next you should learn to use explicit Form instances so that Form2.Show will always refer to the Form instance you think (or want) it to.  Your new method could also be `Public UpdateDisplay(VList as ArrayList)` rather than overriding a standard form method.